# Class 'SessionTrigger' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract member

Tags: scala, abstract-class, apache-flink

I am building a tutorial on Flink 1.2 and I want to run some simple windowing examples. One of them is Session Windows.

The code I want to run is the following:

```
import <package>.Session
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.assigners.GlobalWindows
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.triggers.PurgingTrigger
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.windows.GlobalWindow

import scala.util.Try

object SessionWindowExample {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    val source = env.socketTextStream("localhost", 9000)

    //session map
    val values = source.map(value => {
      val columns = value.split(",")
      val endSignal = Try(Some(columns(2))).getOrElse(None)
      Session(columns(0), columns(1).toDouble, endSignal)
    })

    val keyValue = values.keyBy(_.sessionId)

    // create global window

    val sessionWindowStream = keyValue.
      window(GlobalWindows.create()).
      trigger(PurgingTrigger.of(new SessionTrigger[GlobalWindow]()))

    sessionWindowStream.sum("value").print()

    env.execute()
  }
}
```

As you 'll notice I need to instantiate a `new SessionTrigger` object which I do, based on this class:

```
import <package>.Session
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.triggers.Trigger.TriggerContext
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.triggers.{Trigger, TriggerResult}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.windows.Window

class SessionTrigger[W <: Window] extends Trigger[Session,W] {

  override def onElement(element: Session, timestamp: Long, window: W, ctx: TriggerContext): TriggerResult = {
    if(element.endSignal.isDefined) TriggerResult.FIRE
    else TriggerResult.CONTINUE
  }

  override def onProcessingTime(time: Long, window: W, ctx: TriggerContext): TriggerResult = {
    TriggerResult.CONTINUE
  }
  override def onEventTime(time: Long, window: W, ctx: TriggerContext): TriggerResult = {
    TriggerResult.CONTINUE
  }
}
```

However, InteliJ keeps complaining that:
`Class 'SessionTrigger' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract member 'clear(window: W, ctx: TriggerContext):void' in 'org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.triggers.Trigger'`.

I tried adding this in the class:

```
 override def clear(window: W, ctx: TriggerContext): Unit = ctx.deleteEventTimeTimer(4)
```

but it is not working. This is the error I am getting:

```
  03/27/2017 15:48:38   TriggerWindow(GlobalWindows(), ReducingStateDescriptor{serializer=co.uk.DRUK.flink.windowing.SessionWindowExample.SessionWindowExample$$anon$2$$anon$1@1aec64d0, reduceFunction=org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.aggregation.SumAggregator@1a052a00}, PurgingTrigger(co.uk.DRUK.flink.windowing.SessionWindowExample.SessionTrigger@f2f2cc1), WindowedStream.reduce(WindowedStream.java:276)) -> Sink: Unnamed(4/4) switched to CANCELED
  03/27/2017 15:48:38   Job execution switched to status FAILED.
  Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
  at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6.apply$mcV$sp(JobManager.scala:900)
  at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6.apply(JobManager.scala:843)
  at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6.apply(JobManager.scala:843)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
  at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
  at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
  Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
  at co.uk.DRUK.flink.windowing.SessionWindowExample.SessionWindowExample$$anonfun$1.apply(SessionWindowExample.scala:27)
  at co.uk.DRUK.flink.windowing.SessionWindowExample.SessionWindowExample$$anonfun$1.apply(SessionWindowExample.scala:24)
  at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream$$anon$4.map(DataStream.scala:521)
  at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamMap.processElement(StreamMap.java:38)
  at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamInputProcessor.processInput(StreamInputProcessor.java:185)
  at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OneInputStreamTask.run(OneInputStreamTask.java:63)
  at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:272)
  at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:655)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

  Process finished with exit code 1
```

Anybody know why?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, the error seems pretty self-explanatory. You need to implement the method noted if you want to extend `Trigger` since `Trigger` declares that method as abstract.

Comment: Thanks... let me update my question with what I have tried. (not very good with scala-still learning)

Comment: What do you mean it is not working? If you ask what should you do to compile your example, implementing the `clear` method is enough. As you are not registering anything in the ctx (no timers), your `clear` method should be empty.

Comment: Tried with an empty `clear` method and I am getting the exact same error. Let me add the error I am getting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the exception clearly says

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
  at co.uk.DRUK.flink.windowing.SessionWindowExample.SessionWindowExample$$anonfun$1.apply(SessionWindowExample.scala:27)
  at co.uk.DRUK.flink.windowing.SessionWindowExample.SessionWindowExample$$anonfun$1.apply(SessionWindowExample.scala:24)
```

which obviously maps to the following line of code

```
  Session(columns(0), columns(1).toDouble, endSignal)
```

So the next obvious thing is to log your `columns` and `value` after

```
  val columns = value.split(",")
```

I suspect that `value` just doesn't contain second comma-separated column at least for some values.

Comment: Admittedly, it was all too obvious. There was nothing wrong with the code... It was just my input... Suits me right. Cheers.